# Updating CLOB field in Oracle

Tags: oracle, clob

I have a table in Oracle database with field with data type `CLOB`. The name of field is `XMLString`. I am storing XML string which is 10,000 characters long for each record. I have more than 100, 000 of records in this table.

I need to update segment of the XML string on each record at specific place. For example I need to update each record at 14th position with some string like "My New text".  This replacement text is 11 characters long. So this simply means it will replace 11 characers starting from 14th character.

I tried to use `DBMS_LOB.FRAGMENT_REPLACE`, but it is not exactly what I wanted.

Is there any simple command like

```
Replace(XMLString, 14, ‘My New text’)
```

so that I can do something like below?

```
UPDATE MYTABLE 
SET MyClobField = Replace(MyClobField, 14, 'My New text')
WHERE MyTableID>5000
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SQL using

```
UPDATE MYTABLE 
SET MyClobField = substr(MyClobField, 1, 10) || to_clob('MyNewtext')||substr(MyClobField, 10+length('MyNewtext')+1)
where..
```

just change the 2 occurrences of "10" to the offset.

or in PL/SQL like this using the DBMS_LOB.WRITE API (this is faster than the above)

```
SQL> create table foo(c clob);

Table created.

SQL> insert into foo values ( 'this is a test string ' || rpad('x', 20, 'x'));

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from foo;

C
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
this is a test string xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

SQL> declare
  2    v_lob clob;
  3  begin
  4
  5    for r_lob in (select c
  6                    from foo
  7                    for update)
  8    loop
  9      dbms_lob.write(r_lob.c, 6, 16, 'phrase'); -- ie write at offset 16, 6 bytes
 10    end loop;
 11  end;
 12  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from foo;

C
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
this is a test phrase xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: As `substr()` works on a varchar2, it will fail when the CLOB length is greater than 32767. There are CLOB manipulation functions for this in the `DBMS_LOB` package.

Comment: substr() works on a CLOB and a varchar and will return a CLOB if done on a clob. however, i did miss a TO_CLOB() on the string. so i've added that in. see SYS.STANDARD
`FUNCTION SUBSTR RETURNS CLOB
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 STR1                           CLOB                    IN
 POS                            NUMBER(38)              IN
 LEN                            NUMBER(38)              IN     `

Comment: I used dbms_lob.write(r_lob.c, 6, 16, 'phrase');  as suggested above. But got error ORA-21560: argument 2 is null, invliad, or out of range
ORA-06512: at "Sys.dbms_log", line XXXX
ORA-06512: at line X 
21560. 00000 - "argument %s is null, invalid, out of rance........."

Comment: that was typo. I meant to type LOB, but typed log, which is ovious because i did not write my own error message. 

Can you share how to resolve above issues?
i tried to use dbms_lob.copy, but still could not figure out how to use it.

Comment: Which version of oracle are you on?

Comment: also it would be helpful if you updated the question with your current code with exact error message (dont hide line numbers etc, there's no point) as that answer i provided works ok here on 10.2.0.4 + 11.2.0.1 + 11.2.0.2

Comment: Yes I'm still having an issue with this in Oracle DBaaS 12.2.0.1. I've spent several hours on this between me and another engineer to no avail. Has anyone attempted to update using a Java class in plsql?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

update table set column = replace(column,'hello','abcded')

Answer (score 0):

try this for usefull solution.
this script updates the string between two strings. for instance you have
one unique tag in your xml file. you can change this tag value like below.
if you have more than one tag that you wanted to change than yo need to edit this script. because this script finds only first equality.

```
UPDATE table_name s
   SET s.clobcolumn = substr(s.clobcolumn, 1, to_number(dbms_lob.instr(s.clobcolumn, '<firststring>')) + length('<firststring>')-1) || 'replacestring' ||
                   substr(s.clobcolumn, to_number(dbms_lob.instr(s.clobcolumn, '</secondstring>')) , length(s.clobcolumn))
 WHERE ...
   AND ...
   AND ...;

SELECT to_char(substr(s.clobcolumn,
                      dbms_lob.instr(s.clobcolumn, '<firststring>'),
                      (dbms_lob.instr(s.clobcolumn, '</secondstring>') + length('</secondstring>')) - dbms_lob.instr(s.clobcolumn, '<firststring>'))) replaced_string
  FROM table_name s
 WHERE ...
   AND ...
   AND ...;
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQLDeveloper you can edit CLOBs by clicking on the schema tables and select edit. In the data tab you can generate the update statements for a clob.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :-

```
DECLARE
      str varchar2(32767);
    BEGIN
      str := '<big-string>';
      update <table-name> set <col-name-1>= str where <col-name-2>= ;
    END;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).